# How do I disable an update of a single item?

Tags: icons, update-manager, libreoffice, faenza

I have LibreOffice installed with the [Faenza Icon hack](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=143474). The hack uses the Crystal icon pack. Whenever I update the Crystal icon package, it removes the hack. Is there a way to stop this from happening except manually deselecting it for every update?

Just to be clear. This is what I DON'T want:

- I Don't want to uninstall LibreOffice.
- I don't want to uninstall crystal icon theme.

I simply want to disable the crystal icon theme from ever updating again. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: What package contains that theme?

Comment: Blacklisting packages have been covered on this site, [here][1]. 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24609/blacklisting-packages-from-installing

Comment: pinning and blacklisting have both been covered already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility would be to lock the currently installed version of the Crystal Icon Package. Just choose the package in Synaptic and choose "Lock Version..." from the "Package" menu.

Comment: There were a few comments above regarding this question already being asked. If someone decides to delete this question, please import this answer. This was EXACTLY what I was looking for and 10 times easier than anything found at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24609/blacklisting-packages-from-installing . Thanks, Mrokii!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from blacklisting, the best way to solve this is to add Faenza directly to LibreOffice. If there are no licensing issues, I dont think anyone would resist a fancy new theme! (Note: Ubuntus human theme is also upstreamed)