# how to auto-answer apt-get upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade

When I run `apt-get --yes upgrade` in a script it sometimes stops and prompts for input.

Today in 14.04 LTS it is prompting for what to do for `grub/menu.lst`.   I don't know what could be asked for in a future upgrade.

I tried running this with a newline piped in.  I also tried just a carriage return.  neither worked (seems like the input was lost). I did not find a suitable option in `apt-get` such as `--no-prompts`.

I tried the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104899/make-apt-get-or-aptitude-run-with-y-but-not-prompt-for-replacement-of-configu) but it still gives me a menu prompt asking what config choice I want.

*Any idea how to bypass this prompt?*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i ended up doing `apt-mark hold grub-legacy-ec2` ... the package that was triggering the problem to keep it from updating ... as suggested in a link found here: [Blacklisting grub packages from installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196037/blacklisting-grub-packages-from-installing)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)) command:

```
yes | sudo apt-get --assume-yes upgrade
```

Comment: the grub prompt i get today wants me to select a choice action by moving a selector up or down the press enter.

Comment: it appears to be reading from `/dev/tty` instead of `STDIN`.