# How to prevent updating an application which is not a package?

Tags: fglrx

I loaded AMD's FGLRX drivers and Catalyst manager using a script downloaded from their site  thusly:  made myself root, then  "sh amd-install-correct-fglrx.run" in the recovery mode command line after making / rw and purging as best I could all of the old fglrx stuff.  I did have to use --force to make it work because there was some residual fglrx thing somewhere which survived all the purging.

It works, supports netflix and hdmi sound, and is wonderful in every way until the update manager decides to overwrite it with the vanilla fglrx.

The setup installed as above does not appear as a package and apparently cannot be locked in synaptic package manager.  I suppose I'm asking how to block an update of a package which doesn't reside as such on my machine.

I realize that questions like this have been asked repeatedly but the answers always seem to be aimed at preventing an update of an installed package, not the overwriting of an installation done without a package.

Maybe the best idea would be to figure out what the package would be named if I had it installed and block any updates to that?

Answer (score 0):

You likely are looking to blacklist the installation *(and/or update)* of a package. Instead of looking to blacklist the package you have manually installed, you want to blacklist the overwriting vanilla package *(which would be the package named fglrx or fglrx-*, or similar)*.

This other askubuntu answer outlines how to go about blacklisting a package, which you will want to do to whichever the vanilla fglrx package name is - [Blacklisting packages from installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24609/blacklisting-packages-from-installing)

Comment: hi xLegoz - this looks like exactly what I want.  thanks,  john